# When trying to open a file with Intent getting 'Media not found' error

Tags: java, android, react-native

I download a file and save it as a temporary file using

```
File outputDir = context.getCacheDir();
File f = File.createTempFile(FILE_TYPE_PREFIX, "." + extension,outputDir);
```

*f.exists()* says that the file exists and as well I set *f.setReadable(true, false);* to be able to read it.

The I start a new Intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(f), mimeType);               
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

the f returns

```
/data/user/0/com.app.name/cache/PP_278545395.png
```

and after Uri.fromFile()

```
file:///data/user/0/com.app.name/cache/PP_278545395.png
```

As I try to open the file, it opens the Gallery but tells me "Media not found".

Any ideas why this issue exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getCacheDir()` is part of [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) for your app. Other apps do not have access to it. Use `FileProvider` to publish that content to other apps.

Comment: Can you please expand on that a little bit. I'm quite new to Android/Java.

Comment: @iremlopsum: Well, the question linked to [a blog post explaining what internal storage means with respect to the Android SDK](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html). [Here is a blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/16/how-publish-files-via-content-uri.html) about publishing files via a `content` `Uri`, which is [what `FileProvider` does](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html).

Comment: @iremlopsum: Also, [here is a sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/V4FileProvider) that uses `FileProvider` (serving a PDF copied from `assets/`, so the sample can be bootstrapped).