# Sending image throught my application to whatsapp

Tags: android, image, bitmap, whatsapp

I everyone, I have a problem. I have to send an image to whatsapp from my application. I downloaded the image in bitmap format. After I convert the bitmap format in jpg and I try to send the image. But whatsapp doesn't receive any data.

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");

Bitmap bmp = getBitmap();
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);

File f = new File(getAppContext().getCacheDir() + File.separator + "temporary_file.jpg");
try {
       f.createNewFile();
       FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
       fo.write(stream.toByteArray());
       fo.flush();
       fo.close();
 } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
 }

 shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, f.getPath());
 myShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
```

I have insert into manifest all the permissions.
How Can I fix it?
Thanks.

PS. I use min sdk 17 and max sdk 24

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44639312/115145

Answer (score 1):

WhatsApp doesn't have access to the directory returned by getCacheDir(), only your app does. Try doing it like this instead:

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "temporary_file.jpg");
```

For this to work, you need to declare the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in your manifest.xml file. Like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: I'm trying to create a file using Environment.getExtrnalStorageDirectory() but when I try to createNewFile() it returns IOException permission denied

Comment: Because you need to add the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to your manifest.xml file, I'll edit the answer.